# how to copy out an array of references that are between two values in a ruby string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'd like to get an array of values between delimiters. How would I do this? Like if I was using TN as delimiters and BBCode-type delimiting:

Like:

```
a="things [TN]are like[/TN] this [TN]for you[/TN]"
b=a.xxxx
b=["are like","for you"]
```

Comment: You may want to explain what you have tried and what went wrong. Did you try to use `scan`?

Comment: scan - ah, not yet, was thinking match or split but knew there had to be a better way. partition, maybe???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're certain that there won't be any nested `[TN]...[/TN]` tags, then you can use a simple regex for this:

```
a.scan(/(?<=\[TN\]).*?(?=\[\/TN\])/)
```

Comment: cool thx - exactly what I was looking for! I think I would have spent a solid morning trying to get there (and probably wouldn't have been as elegant).  Yeah, as long as it requires both sides, I'm ok with the non-nested [TN][/TN]

Comment: Well, I certainly love creating regexes, glad I could help!  Yeah, if you end up with nested tags, the matches will be incorrect.

Comment: You can add the `m` modifier to match the newline character too (just put `m` after the last `/`).